# Python random data generator adding spaces to a csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a project and one part of it is using randomly generated data for the system. I have a random data generator but for some reason when it generates the data it adds random blank lines in the file.

What its supposed to do:

```
Canada1,CAN,66.7631001973005,327464,124083,37.208477068753076,42.055800430596044,Tree1,Sport1,Energy1
Canada2,CAN,63.42569986832592,845406,2564,99.41705285611631,58.367586898438226,Tree2,Sport2,Energy2
Canada3,CAN,80.70135666200893,697617,552814,45.0220391009484,27.55749551009966,Tree3,Sport3,Energy3
Canada4,CAN,39.91456647957388,378395,859154,49.04878526186859,58.29166138539077,Tree4,Sport4,Energy4
Canada5,CAN,23.665606706690824,27748,50323,46.099226214455754,46.02385899749339,Tree5,Sport5,Energy5
Canada6,CAN,99.11484943040361,463793,926721,22.623982535050036,68.17148628441608,Tree6,Sport6,Energy6
Canada7,CAN,22.77326723315597,197781,161989,90.07404212037031,12.51439909283495,Tree7,Sport7,Energy7
Canada8,CAN,98.05987017622658,22699,686789,79.69776439153054,88.97691373932459,Tree8,Sport8,Energy8
Canada9,CAN,74.7926432968632,973377,656871,47.67399967110805,69.30160579846151,Tree9,Sport9,Energy9
Canada10,CAN,58.42869917577311,720578,266173,62.941805567587686,75.31905104550286,Tree10,Sport10,Energy10
```

What its doing:

```
Canada1,CAN,66.7631001973005,327464,124083,37.208477068753076,42.055800430596044,Tree1,Sport1,Energy1

Canada2,CAN,63.42569986832592,845406,2564,99.41705285611631,58.367586898438226,Tree2,Sport2,Energy2

Canada3,CAN,80.70135666200893,697617,552814,45.0220391009484,27.55749551009966,Tree3,Sport3,Energy3

Canada4,CAN,39.91456647957388,378395,859154,49.04878526186859,58.29166138539077,Tree4,Sport4,Energy4

Canada5,CAN,23.665606706690824,27748,50323,46.099226214455754,46.02385899749339,Tree5,Sport5,Energy5

Canada6,CAN,99.11484943040361,463793,926721,22.623982535050036,68.17148628441608,Tree6,Sport6,Energy6

Canada7,CAN,22.77326723315597,197781,161989,90.07404212037031,12.51439909283495,Tree7,Sport7,Energy7

Canada8,CAN,98.05987017622658,22699,686789,79.69776439153054,88.97691373932459,Tree8,Sport8,Energy8

Canada9,CAN,74.7926432968632,973377,656871,47.67399967110805,69.30160579846151,Tree9,Sport9,Energy9

Canada10,CAN,58.42869917577311,720578,266173,62.941805567587686,75.31905104550286,Tree10,Sport10,Energy10
```

Here is the generator

```
import random
import os
import csv

# Generating random data. The car information is not important, rather the car vin number needs to be unique
def generate_data_csv(rand_file_name, no_entries):
  # rand_file_name: the name of the random 
  # no_entries: the number of entries in the file
  
  file_name = "temp.csv" # temp file to hold the generated entries
  with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writefile = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(1, no_entries+1):
      country_name=("Canada" + str(i))
      country_code="CAN"
      access_to_electricity=(random.uniform(0.0, 100.0))
      renewable_electricity_output=(random.randint(1000,1000000))
      total_electricity_output=(random.randint(1000,1000000))
      tot_final_energy_consumption=(random.uniform(0.0, 100.0))
      renewable_energy_consumption=(random.uniform(0.0, 100.0))
      national_tree=("Tree" + str(i))
      most_popular_sport=("Sport" + str(i))
      primary_energy_consumption=("Energy" + str(i))
      row = [country_name,country_code,access_to_electricity,renewable_electricity_output,total_electricity_output,tot_final_energy_consumption,renewable_energy_consumption,national_tree,most_popular_sport,primary_energy_consumption]
      writefile.writerow(row)
  # randmize the entries in the file
  with open(file_name,'r') as source:
    csvreader = csv.reader(source)
    data = [ (random.random(), line) for line in csvreader ]
  data.sort()
  with open(rand_file_name,'w') as target:
    writefile = csv.writer(target)
    for _, line in data:
        writefile.writerow(line)

  # removing the temp file, not needed anymore
  os.remove(file_name)
```

Ive tried removing the second section of the code that randomizes the position of the data, and it still came out the same.

Comment: What OS are you using? Works fine for me.  I'm wondering if the is a Windoze CR-LF issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `csv.writer` will create line endings as `\r\n` as is the default for Windows, probably because it is the default for Excel in any system.

The software you are using to look at the file is making each of the `\r` and `\n` characters to behave like a newline, instead of combining both as a single "new line" as Windows does by default.

You can simply make explicit what the `csv.writer` is to use as line ending, and you should have a nicely formatted file on Linux and MacOS apps (which might have problems loading in Excel, though):

`writefile = csv.writer(target, lineterminator="\n")`